# Understanding star domains.

Tags: complex-analysis

I will star by giving the definition of a *star domain*:

**An open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a $\underline{star}$ $\underline{domain}$  if $\exists c \in U, \forall z \in U, [c,z] = \{(1-t)c+tz, 0≤t≤1 \} \subset U$**

Now I wanna try and understand that concept through simple examples I've seen in class (I have trouble understanding both of them)  :

- $\underline{example-1}$: Is $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_-$ a star domain. All the professor said is: yes because all the points of $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ can be centers.

What does he mean by centers, does he simply mean that if you take $c \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ then $[c,z] \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_-$

- $\underline{example - 2}$: Same thing for $U =  \mathbb{C} \setminus i \mathbb{R}_+$

Answer (score 2):

I give you the same definition in "words":

A subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is called "star domain" iff there is a center $c\in U$ so that for every $z\in U$ the closed line segment between $c$ and $z$ is part of $U$.

Do you see now, why your examples are star domains?